# ¿ Una vez he terminado el desarrollo de una aplicación en java, Como hago para que la misma se pueda instalar en diferentes computadores?

Tags: java, aplicación-escritorio

Tal vez el titulo de la pregunta no es muy claro, pero mi duda es la siguiente. Una vez que se ha finalizado el desarrollo de una aplicación en java, y por tanto esta ya es completamente funcional, que se debe hacer para que esta se pueda instalar y funcione correctamente en cualquier computador. Es decir, hasta ahora solo me han enseñado a ejecutar la aplicación dentro del mismo ide del desarrollo, pero si quisiera vender mi programa, obviamente quien lo compre lo hará fuera del ide, como si fuese un programa cualquiera.

Comment: Googleando un poco puedes leer aquí https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html

Comment: Si no recuerdo mal Netbeans te dejaba exportar tu archivo java(no estoy seguro si era netbeans o eclipse) en otro formato de archivo para poder ejecutarlo simplemente

Answer (score 1):

Para poder ejecutar una aplicación Java fuera de tu entorno de desarrollo es necesario compilar y construir la misma para generar un archivo ejecutable con la extensión `.jar` (esto también aplica para tu entorno de desarrollo o IDE, la diferencia es que en este caso, cuando tú haces clic en el botón para ejecutar la aplicación, el IDE realiza estos pasos por ti).

#### La manera fácil:

Dependiendo del IDE que utilices seguramente puedes encontrar una opción para construir (build, deploy, etc) tu aplicación y generar este archivo `.jar`, cabe destacar que para ejecutar una aplicación Java es necesario que el equipo donde se pretenda ejecutar la aplicación (el cliente) tenga instalado un entorno de ejecución Java (JRE).
Te recomiendo que empieces por aquí para que te familiarices con el concepto y luego pases a explorar la forma más completa de hacerlo.

#### La manera completa:

Adicionalmente, puedes compilar y construir una aplicación Java de forma “manual” utilizando tu línea de comandos y la herramienta javac (que es precisamente el compilador que convierte tus archivos `.java` donde escribes tu código, en archivos `.class` que contienen bytecode o código que la Java Virtual Machine puede interpretar y ejecutar). Esta forma es mas completa porque puedes especificar muchas opciones al momento de compilar o construir tu aplicación.

En cualquiera de los casos te recomiendo realizar una búsqueda especificando la opción que prefieras, por ejemplo:

- ¿Cómo construir una aplicación Java en [tu IDE]?
- ¿Cómo compilar y construir una aplicación Java utilizando javac en línea de comandos?